Geospatial Support in SAI in Cassandra 5.0
I am evaluating the capabilities of Storage Attached Indexing (SAI) in Apache Cassandra 5.0, particularly in relation to handling geospatial data. I understand that SAI aims to enhance indexing efficiency within Cassandra, but I am interested in its support and functionality for geospatial types and queries.
Could anyone provide insights into whether SAI supports complex geospatial data types such as points, lines, and polygons, and if it can perform operations like proximity searches, intersections, and distance calculations? Additionally, does SAI offer geospatial indexing that improves performance for these types of queries, and is it compatible with geospatial data standards such as WKT or WKB?
Similar functionality to Cassandra Lucene Index
Any guidance on how SAI integrates with these geospatial capabilities, or pointers to relevant documentation or examples, would be greatly appreciated.
Looked at CEPs/Jiras/existing documentation.
